# Difference between focus, focusleave,focusenter with extjs

Tags: button, extjs, focus, listener

Can anyone explain me what the difference between focus, focusleave and focusenter on button method with extjs, I'm lost because it seems to be the same when I add event listener. Thanks

kind regards

Answer (score 2):

> difference between focus, focusleave and focusenter on button method
>   with extjs

Method? I guess you mean the events right? Cos:

The [focus](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#method-focus) method will focus your button when you call it.

[image]

As you can see on the picture the middle button has focus, you can change the focus on the webpage usually by using TAB key. ExtJS supports full control over your app using keyboard.

---

The [focus](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#event-focus), [focusenter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#event-focusenter), [focusleave](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#event-focusleave) events. **If you are not sure what to use - just use "focus"**

The **focus** event should be clear - it's simply fired when the button has focus.

The **focusenter** is fired when the component get's focus but as the docs states it's also fired in the whole component hirearchy. That means that if the button is in panel which is in view and you focus the button - the focusenter will be fired on the view, panel, button.

main -> panel -> button

[image: component hirearchy]

Events
[image]

The **focusleave** is the same as focus enter. Fired when focus is lost on the component - again fired in the whole hirearchy. So if the focus went completly away form the page you would see focus leave on the button -> panel -> view

Comment: Thank you so much it's very helpful,

Comment: @rhf I am glad it helped you. Btw don't forget to mark the "correct" answers on your questions ;-)